# How many combinations of this tuple are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Given a tuple $(x,y,z)$ with $x,y,z \in \{1,...,10\}$ and $x<y-1<z-2$, how many combinations are possible? I know that $x$ can't be $10,9,8$ or $7$, but I am not sure how to calculate the exact number of possible combinations.

Comment: So in other words, you ask how many subsets of size three there are from $\{1,2,\dots,10\}$ consisting of non-consecutive integers?  Try looking at the related quadruple talking about the distance from $1$ to $x$, the distance from $x$ to $y$, the distance from $y$ to $z$ and the distance from $z$ to $10$.

Comment: The sum of the terms in $((x-1),(y-x),(z-y),(10-z))$ will be $9$, the first and last term may be any non-negative integer, and the middle two terms must be integers at least $2$.  Can you find how many non-negative integral solutions there are to $\begin{cases}a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=9\\a_1\geq 0\\a_2\geq 2\\a_3\geq 2\\a_4\geq 0\end{cases}$?  The phrase 'stars-and-bars' will likely come up in most people's solutions/approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Take $10$ balls, label $3$ of them $x,y,z$, glue one ball each to the right of $x$ and of $y$ to enfore the inequalities, and then count the ways to choose $3$ spots for $x,y,z$ in the arrangements of the resulting $8$ objects.

Comment: Why one ball to the right of y and not 2 balls? And can I express this answer with a combination $C(n,r)$?

Comment: @PhillipJones: I don't see why it should be two. You have two identical inequalities, $x<y-1$ and $y<z-1$, I don't see a reason to treat them any differently. I wanted to leave the final step to you, but yes, you can: You can choose $3$ spots for $x,y,z$ among these $8$ objects in $\binom83$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the range of values for $y=(x+1, 7)$ and the range of values for $z=(y+1, 10)$.

From these intervals, we deduce that for any $x\in\{1,...,7\}$, there are $7-x$ values for $y$. For any $y\in\{2,...,7-x\}$, there are $9-y$ values for $z$. The number of possible combinations is thus $$\prod_{x=1}^6\prod_{y=2}^{7-x}x(7-x)(9-y)$$ Plug this in Wolfram Alpha or do this by hand (if you prefer) should give you the answer.